# Some CSS not working correctly when using an alias to enter website

Tags: internet-explorer-8, css, alias

I have built an intranet for my company, but when I access the site using an alias (DrewNett) so of the styling in IE is incorrect. It's only in IE, and the source is exactly the same and when I go do the site using the FQD.

Is there any kind of issues with IE (silly question, I konw!) that may be causing this?

Also, does anybody have so ideas for trouble shooting, as I'm kind of stumped.

It's IE8 that is being used.

**Answer** - This was happening because IE8 was automatically displaying the site in Compatibility View because it was picking it up as an Intranet site. To stop this, in IE, go 'Tools -> Compatibility Veiw Settings', and then uncheck 'Display intranet site in Compatibility View'.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe the CSS references an image file by full URL (maybe `spacer.gif`) and IE treats it like XSS or something equally weird.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg - No images in affected areas. The site is Wordpress, so all URL's point to the correct place any way because I always use there functions for making links, etc. It's really odd as very little is affected, so clearly the CSS is being accessed.

Comment: Given this issue is primarily a visual one, some screenshots might help. Hard to make any assumptions.

Comment: Ok, so it's because the site is being forced in to 'compatibility mode', but without the option to turn it off. Screenshots - will sort some and post a link shortly.

Comment: ...And I've sorted it - In IE, go 'Tools -> Compatibility Veiw Settings', and then uncheck 'Display intranet site in Compatibility View'.

Comment: Great :) Would be nice if you could post this as an answer and mark it as accepted when you can.

Comment: I'm unable to self-answer yet due to my reputaion (I'm a newbie), so will do when I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was happening because IE8 was automatically displaying the site in Compatibility View because it was picking it up as an Intranet site. To stop this, in IE, go 'Tools -> Compatibility Veiw Settings', and then uncheck 'Display intranet site in Compatibility View'.